# Working with older Xcode project, screen size prints wrong resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm working with a project I created a few years ago.

When I run it in the iPhone 7 simulator, I'm getting the wrong resolution:

```
screensize {568, 320}
```

This is the older iPhone 5s resolution, the correct iPhone 7 resolution should be `{667, 375}` (landscape app).

I'm guessing some scale virtualization is occurring to scale older projects up or something? Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have to add a launch screen storyboard or launch images for the larger devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears project without storyboards/launch storyboards fall back on some screen scaling, ie. your app will run at older iPhone resolutions.